# How can install maven2 and maven3 and have them coexist on the same ubuntu host

Tags: maven

I found that maven2 install is via apt-get and maven3 is manual, but i could not find any information on how i an install maven3 without uninstalling maven2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download maven and extract it to a folder (eg `/opt/maven3`)
- Add maven link to PATH : ln -s /opt/maven3/mvn /usr/local/bin/mvn3

Use maven3 with mvn3 command, and maven2 with mvn command.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630055/how-to-install-maven-3-on-ubuntu-12-10-by-using-apt-get) for the manual MVN 3 installation. There is also an answer on how to install it automatically.